# Check if object is Null in Linq Query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

How do you check if an object is empty with a LINQ query ?

If the object is empty I want to omit it from the search.

I don't want to do an If Else statement and duplicate code and check if the object is Null before the query. At the moment my query will return an error if the object is not empty "Nullable object must have a value."

```
public ActionResult Search(List<int> accountStatus = null , string accountName = "", int pageId = 1)
    {
        var model = Db.Entities
            .Where(i => i.GroupId == null && i.IsActive)
            .Where(an => string.IsNullOrEmpty(accountName) || (an.Name.StartsWith(accountName) || an.Name.Contains(accountName)))
            .ToList()
            .Where(accs => accountStatus == null || accountStatus.Contains((int)accs.CurrentStatusId.Value))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedDate);    

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("********", model.ToPagedList(pageId, nbItemsPerPage));
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Which line is returning the error?

Comment: You indeed might want to tell which property is `null`. Also, why do a `ToList` in the middle of your code?

Comment: `.Where(accs => accountStatus == null || accountStatus.Contains((int)accs.CurrentStatusId.Value))`

Comment: And what property is null?

Comment: accs.CurrentStatusId is null?

Comment: If I don't do a `ToList` I can't check if the object is `null` in the query

Comment: The `accountStatus` is `null`

Comment: Why are you checking `accountStatus` for nullity (`==null`) ? Don't you want to make sure it's *not null*?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the `accountstatus` is a multiselect dropdown where the user can filter their search. If the user doesn't select anything a null object is returned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to let all `accs` pass when `accountStatus` is `null`, do this:

```
.Where( accs => accs != null
                && ( accountStatus == null
                     || accountStatus.Contains(accs.CurrentStatusId.GetValueOrDefault(-1))
                   )
      )
```